# How to add a bullet point in a form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I have a javascript code inside a form, This javascript is supposed to put a bullet point to the previous line, every time that I press the 'enter' key. However, when I do press the enter key it does put the bullet point, but when I press the enter key again, an additional bullet appears. For instance, I have line 1, line 2, and line 3. When I type line one and press enter, a bullet appears behind line one, but when I type line 2 and press enter, line one suddenly has 2 bullets behind it and line 2 has a bullet added to it.

---

This is the code:

```
// Function to format the "roles" textarea into bullet points
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id === 'id_form-0-roles' && e.keyCode === 13) {
            formatRoles(e.target);
            e.preventDefault();

        }
    });

    function formatRoles(textarea) {
        let lines = textarea.value.split('\n');
        let formattedText = '';
        lines.forEach(function (line) {
            if (line.trim() !== '') {
                formattedText += '• ' + line.trim() + '\n';
            } else {
                formattedText += '\n'; // Add a new line for empty lines
            }
        });
        textarea.value = formattedText;
    }

</script>
```

I expect the javascript to put just one bullet point in the preceding line after the enter key is pressed, such that each line has a bullet point behind it. This is what I want:

- line 1
- line 2
- line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When formatRoles sets the value for lines, its splits the entire existing textarea text by the new lines. The bullet points are characters in the text area, so after typing the first line the result for array lines is ["• hello","world"] and then you append a bullet to each resulting in ["• • hello","• world","another new line"] and so on.

A solution for this would be looking at only the last line when adding the bullet.

```js
// Function to format the "roles" textarea into bullet points
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.target.id === "id_form-0-roles" && e.keyCode === 13) {
    formatRoles(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

function formatRoles(textarea) {
  let lines = textarea.value.split("\n");
  let formattedText = "";
  lines.forEach((line, i) => {
    if (i === lines.length - 1 && line.trim() !== "") { //only apply the bullet if its the last line and not empty.
      formattedText += "• " + line.trim() + "\n";
    } else {
      formattedText += line + "\n";
    }
  });
  textarea.value = formattedText;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="id_form-0-roles" style="width: 400px;height:100px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hello @cub, thank you for your contribution. upon implementing those changes, the code is still not working as intended, so I see that now when I click enter a bullet point is displayed but when I type another sentence and press enter, the first line is substituted by the second line.

Comment: whoops fixed. same idea still, only add the bullet on the last line.